# bootstrap 3 show label in inline selectbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I set label for select box menu in bootstrap 3 like this :

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <label>Filter</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="sort">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

in output in see label in top of select box menu:
[image]

I need to show label inline of select box menu like this :

[image]

how do show label in inline ?!

DEMO [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8oom89kf/1/)

Comment: Read the Bootstrap docs http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need put your label and your select inside of a "group", so we have this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sort" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Filter </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" name="sort" id="sort">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
        </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried exactly same thing for BS4 but its not working:
<div class="form-group" >
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="doc_type">Select </label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<select class="form-control" id="doc_type" name="doc_type">
.... all options here ....
</select>
</div>
</div>
can anybody suggest what wrong i m doing here?

Comment: @Aqeel, I think you have to add row class in first div! See: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JmLqMY

Answer (score 0):

You want `form-inline` - This example works in full screen mode (not sure why this code snippet wraps when not in full screen mode) but give it a whirl it should work for you.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="dashboard-filter">Filter By</label>
    <select id="dashboard-filter" class="form-control">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Docs are here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#forms-inline